# using regular expression: validate email address

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Hi I'm a newbie about the using of regular expression
I have this regular expression to validate an mail but I don't understand the meaning.Someone could explain me?

```
mailPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_0-9]*[.[a-zA-Z_0-9]*]*@[a-zA-Z_0-9]*[.[a-zA-Z_0-9]*]*.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}");
```

Comment: This is not a full pattern to validate an email address. take a look at the link I have put.

Comment: The answer specified in the link is useful, but not the best solution when using Java.  Java/JavaMail already has a [built-in class](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html) that parses e-mail addresses based upon RFC822 specs.  Using that is preferable to using any regex directly.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Java, a much simpler option is to use JavaMail's `InternetAddress` class to validate the address for you:

```
public boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    try {
        new InternetAddress(email);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will perform validation based upon [RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt).  There's no need to try to come up with your own regex, really, or to copy regex's that others have come up with.  Just use JavaMail's built-in utility, and move on to more meaningful things.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you the excellent web site http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to start learning regex

But your regex does not seems good. There is no need to have the asterix in a set.

here is the bad code : [.[a-zA-Z_0-9]*]

You need to use + instead of * in some part of your regex, etc.

validating email with regex is explained here (I recommend you to read it and use one of their regex instead of yours) :
http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: `.name` has been around for a frikkin *decade*! But nooooo, every TLD is three characters at most. Oh, and there's no such thing as `+` allowed in the local part (and that's before resorting to the more exotic characters like `%`), right? And IDNs don't exist. The problems with that regex are far too numerous :(

Comment: completely agree. I first try to write a post on all errors and finally edited my post to add the link to the website ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, *that* website. Note that the page you link to says this, essentially: "This regex validates all valid e-mail addresses (btw, when I say 'all e-mail addresses', I mean 'everything matched by this regex'; I don't give a damn that actual valid e-mail address not matching this exist)." Circular reasoning at its finest.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at Java SE tutorial on regular expressions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).